# How to Deploy ML Recommender System on AWS

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, tfidfvectorizer

I'm dabbling with ML and was able to take a tutorial and get it to work for my needs.  It's a simple recommender system using TfidfVectorizer and linear_kernel.  I run into a problem with how I go about deploying it through Sagemaker with an end point.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel 
import json
import csv

with open('data/big_data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

ds = pd.DataFrame(data)

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(ds['content'])
cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

results = {}

for idx, row in ds.iterrows():
    similar_indices = cosine_similarities[idx].argsort()[:-100:-1]
    similar_items = [(cosine_similarities[idx][i], ds['id'][i]) for i in similar_indices]

    results[row['id']] = similar_items[1:]

def item(id):
    return ds.loc[ds['id'] == id]['id'].tolist()[0]

def recommend(item_id, num):
    print("Recommending " + str(num) + " products similar to " + item(item_id) + "...")
    print("-------")
    recs = results[item_id][:num]
    for rec in recs:
        print("Recommended: " + item(rec[1]) + " (score:" + str(rec[0]) + ")")

recommend(item_id='129035', num=5)
```

As a starting point I'm not sure if the output from `tf.fit_transform(ds['content'])` is considered the model or the output from `linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that I didn't need to deploy this through SageMaker.  Since the final linear_kernel output was a Dictionary I could do quick ID lookups to find correlations.

I have it working on AWS with API Gateway/Lambda, DynamoDB and an EC2 server to collect, process and plug the data into DynamoDB for fast lookups.  No expensive SageMaker endpoint needed.